# Rails 5 not saving to my table using nested forms in Ruby-on-Rails using Cocoon gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

RAILS 5 PROBLEM. I have a project and I wanted the user to have the option to add extra items to the form. My code renders correctly and it the link to add more fields does add more text field. The problem I have is that is not saving the to my database. I am using mysql2 gem on a MySQl database. I posted the console output. This is what I have:

**forms_controller**

```
  # forms_controller.rb
  def new
    @form = Form.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @form }
    end
  end
  def create
    @form = Form.new(form_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @form.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@form, :notice => 'form was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @form, :status => :created, :location => @form }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @form.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def form_params
    params.require(:form).permit(:name, items_attributes: [:id, :item_name, :_destroy])
  end
```

**models**

```
# form.rb
class Form < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates_presence_of :name
end

# item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :form
end
```

**views**

```
<!-- _form.html.haml -->

= form_for @form do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :name
    %br
    = f.text_field :name
  %h3 items
  #items
    = f.fields_for :items do |item|
      = render 'item_fields', f: item
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add item', f, :items
  = f.submit
```

```
.nested-fields
  .field
    = f.label :item_name
    %br
    = f.text_field :item_name
  = link_to_remove_association "remove item", f
```

**console**

```
tarted POST "/forms" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-08 23:04:17 -0600
Processing by FormsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FmYPwlXy93iwBMkWvfyd3QJ+NKDcYnraUaKmMISbUIX3+KRL7KtpD33FW3CK+jxvn4AoUUMhx4zrGncJej5BOw==", "form"=>{"name"=>"sfsf", "items_attributes"=>{"1473397456358"=>{"item_name"=>"sfsf", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Form"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering forms/new.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered forms/_item_fields.html.haml (1.5ms)
  Rendered forms/_item_fields.html.haml (1.2ms)
  Rendered forms/_form.html.haml (8.5ms)
  Rendered forms/new.html.haml within layouts/application (10.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 54.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: in your permit/require line (in your controller), `item_attribute` should probably be `item_attributes` (there's more than one)

Comment: Does your code here contain all validations? Because this looks a validation error (now), if I read your logfile correctly, you get a rollback before actually any SQL is executed, so this would suggest a validation on the rails-side is blocking actually even trying to save the data to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it wouldn't save is because I was using Rails 5 and I needed to add `optional: true` to the belongs_to in the item model.

```
# form.rb
class Form < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates_presence_of :name
end

# item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :form , optional: true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

in your permit/require line (in your controller), `item_attribute` should probably be `item_attributes` (there's more than one) ie:

```
def form_params
  params.require(:form).permit(:name, :date_sent, :quantity, :comment, item_attributes: [:id, :name, :form_id, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: I saw that but it still doesn't work. Now I get a begin and rollback and it makes no changes to the database at all. I recently updated my inquery and the the current code is up. I change my code to look more like a scaffold because I thought maybe I was doing something wrong. I was following this gem. https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: it is definitely that which is causing your current error... you may also have another error, that is now revealed. (the fun of nested errors) :)

Comment: I am thinking my problem could be that I am using mysql2. Did you ever had problem in rails doing nested loop using mysql for the database?

Comment: I usually use postgres... but it shouldn't be the problem here. It is very difficult if you update the question and remove the original data... the answers and comments then don't make sense anymore... normally we add an extra update to the original question with the new info, rather than changing it to match new knowledge - that way people looking back at this question can see how things evolved over time :)

Comment: I fixed it. I just needed to add optional: true to my belongs_to on my Item model. I think this was an issue with rails 5. Also, I meant to say nested forms. I was so desperate I payed someone to help me fix this. I am now cruising right along on my development. Thanks for help.

Comment: paying somebody else is a great solution, especially if it gets you moving again :)

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 5, whenever we define a belongs_to association, it is required to have the associated record present by default after this change.

It triggers validation error if associated record is not present.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

post = Post.create(title: 'Hi')
=> <Post id: nil, title: "Hi", user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
=> "User must exist"
```

****Opting out of this default behavior in Rails 5****

We can pass optional: true to the belongs_to association which would remove this validation check.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user, optional: true

end

post = Post.create(title: 'Hi')

=> <Post id: 2, title: "Hi", user_id: nil>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!